# How to know about the hardware especifications of a notebook/ultrabook?

Tags: laptop, memory, ssd

I'm a .Net programmer and I want to buy a new ultrabook for me. I'm dating the Dell XPS 13 and I want to know the hardware manufacturer and version of the SSD and memory, but I don't find it on the internet. Where can I find these hardware especifcations?

I don't have the laptop at hands. I want to see this especifcations of a specific laptop and decide whether I'll buy or not.

Comment: have you powered it down and taken it apart?

Comment: Since it appears you're wanting this information before purchasing a device, it might be prudent to ask the sales team?  In this case, call Dell and ask any questions you want before you buy.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- You're a programmer -- [use .NET](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-WMI-with-C-4e5a9ee1) and [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx) calls.
- Run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or alike.
- Assuming Windows; open the Device Manager, look under Disk Drives.
- Bust out a screw driver, open the notebook and look at the labels.

Comment: make sure to remove the battery before disassembling

Comment: I don't have the laptop at hands. I want to see this especifcations of a specific laptop and decide whether I'll buy or not.

Comment: If you can't touch it or look at it, then you have to ask a sales person.